# Why does Spock want to suppress certain knowledge?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

At the end of *Discovery* season 2, Spock suggests during his debriefing that all knowledge of Discovery be suppressed, including that of the spore drive.  He seems to imply that the only people with knowledge of the drive were directly involved in the final battle, but that's not true from season 1, where Starfleet is trying to replicate the drive.  To keep it a secret would be practically impossible, and it isn't something that Control would need anyway.

Other than to close the obvious plot hole that the drive is never mentioned again, why would the spore drive be classified along with the sphere data/knowledge of Control?

Comment: @Jonita When adding a specific work tag, you should keep the franchise tag i.e. in this case this should be tagged with [[tag:star-trek-discovery]] ___and___ [[tag:star-trek]].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spock's actual lines in that scene are:

> SPOCK: The destruction of Discovery was tragic but does in and of
>   itself resolve the issue. Even more radical steps must be taken to
>   ensure that type of scenario never repeats itself.

and

> Any residual trace or knowledge of Discovery's data, or the time suit,
>   offers a foothold for those who might not see how critical, how deeply
>   critical, that directive is.

What Spock is suggesting here is that any information about the Discovery *or anything related to it* could give someone (or something) in the future hints that might ultimately lead them to discover the existence of the time suit and it's technology. If the time suit was re-discovered it would threaten the entire timeline.

Therefore, Spock proposes that all possible leads to the time suit be purged/destroyed - that includes all information relating to Discovery, including the Spore drive it contained, as well as the time suit itself. The Federation are not "evil" so they don't can't just disappear all the surviving crew, but they can make them swear to secrecy for the rest of their lives (there are real-world examples of this kind of thing occurring).

Or, as Spock himself puts it:

> Therefore, to ensure the Federation never finds itself facing the same
>   danger, all officers remaining with knowledge of these events must be
>   ordered never to speak of Discovery, its spore drive, or her crew
>   again. Under penalty of treason.

Note he doesn't mention officers of the Discovery specifically, it's "all officers" [of Starfleet].

Out of universe this does of course also tie up the huge plot hole, which is that no one in any of the shows set chronologically after Discovery ever mentions spore drives or the Discovery.

Comment: Can you elaborate on those real-world examples?

Comment: @user Off the top of my head, during WW2 the British "Auxilary Unit" members (a secret guerilla organisation formed in case of a successful German invasion of the UK) had to sign the Official Secrets Act and swear not to reveal anything about the existence of the organisation or their activities for 50 years - OK, not quite the rest of their lives, but many actually did keep it secret until their final days.